# My Java Code does't compile. Where could the error be? And what is the output?

Tags: java, output

I am tryin to run this Java code, but Eclipse can't compile it. What is the error and what should the output be?

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 7};

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
{
 if (a[i] > 5) 
 {
   System.out.println(a[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you enclose this in a method which belongs to a class? Java code cannot exist without a defining method which has to be part of a class.

Comment: Your code is not compiling. Are you sure your compilation error is coming from these line? Please add the whole code

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if your code is bug-free, however you may not have included the proper class and method structure in your program.

In order for your Java code to run, it needs an enclosing class and method. Inside a class which is compiled and run, the Java program looks for a main method to invoke and all the code within is run. Java is an object oriented language, so you can call other methods to run code segments within them.

Please see the [Official Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) by Oracle for more. This very specifically will teach you about program structure.

```
public class ClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 7};
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > 5) {
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your code in a `main` method that is defined in a class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
       int[] a = { 1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 7 };

       for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
           if (a[i] > 5) {
               System.out.println(a[i]);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

`main` serves as the entry point of your program and must be defined in a class like all methods in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enclose this within the class.
You need to have a main method in order to run the program.
Optionally you can include this piece of code you pasted in your question inside a method and call the method in the main program.

I just ran your code and the output of your code is

> 6
>
> 8
>
> 7

Comment: yes, after I included a main method, I got the same output. thanks for your help!